# Ionic build faild:

Tags: ionic-framework

When I build a new ionic app to android , 
Compilation failed . 
The error is as follows：

```
* What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
 Required by:
     project :
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
     > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom'.
           > Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

Anyone can help me? I am confused.

Comment: It seems that you don't have Gradle installed.

Comment: Do I need to download it independently ? I have installed android studio ,which seems  have gradle when i start a new andorid project.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know how to solve this problem.

- First steps: Ansure have download jdk and set the 'java_home' and 'classpath';
- Second steps: Ansure have download node, which verison is 1.8+;
- Third steps : Downloading android studio , in this step will auto upset gradle and SDK;

***After do above three steps, u can use android studio create a new blank android app an run simulator.***

- The last steps: set system enviroment variable 'SDK_HOME' and 'ANDROID_HOME' like this:

**ANDROID_HOME**  `E:\sdk (this is my computer setting)`

**SDK_HOME**      `E:\sdk`

**path** `%SDK_HOME%\tools;%SDK_HOME%\platformtools;C:\Users\xxxxx\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-3.1`

***EDIT:***

Correction in folder name: platform-tools

`%SDK_HOME%\tools;%SDK_HOME%\platform-tools;C:\Users\xxxxx\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-3.1`